# android: how to center block in relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout where red block is centered in black region, and blue rect is need to be centered between white and red blocks. Does anybody know how to make a frame of such layout?

[image]

Comment: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

none of the other answers truly answer the question, the question clearly identifies, red box on center and blue box centered above the red.

In order to accomplish that you'll need to mix the parameters from the Relative Layout with the parameters of whatever the BlueBox is, here is an example using TextViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

textView2 is above textView1 and parentTop, so it will occupay all that space. Then you use it's own internal gravity to center Vertical to make it's content centered there.

Comment: can you just set background of middle Textview, how much height it covers?

Comment: but that height varies a lot depending on the device screen size and orientation. That way you're just letting the system automatically calculate it for you.

Comment: Agree but when you look at OP's post(image) see middle blue portion its having margins proportionately but in your case it will not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to play with few of properties of relative layout to your views to achieve your goal, You have to do something like below:

[image]

Apply mentioned properties to your view, you will get your result.

for further info, refer below link

[Relative layout](http://android-pro.blogspot.in/2010/03/relative-layout.html)

Comment: same as all the others. Incomplete answer.

Comment: @Budius Its coincident while I'm answering, along me two answers were posted too and its not same its similar, and regarding incomplete, will edit my answer.

Comment: It's my technical opinion, and it seems that you're taking as a personal attack. It's not. Let's just keep it the technical level. if you care so much, here, I'll remove! (it will allow me to do it in 14min)

Comment: @Budius no, actually I was expecting a comment while someone downvote, and its a good habit too, so I (users) will correct them, without knowing how can anyone, and nothing:)

Comment: I can see you edited your question adding a XML layout. But this layout is still incorrect. It will not render the correct answer. Thou, I'm keeping the downvote. If you want feel free to copy from my answer. You have to properly allocate the `layout_above` and `layout_below` parameters.

Comment: @Budius when you applying  `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` & `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` its not require to add, instead if your view just below another view then in case, you have to `layout_above` and `layout_below`

Comment: I understand what you said and just put your answer in a layout here and indeed renders white on top, blue in mid, red on bottom. But the question is: white on top, red in mid, and blue between white and red

Comment: @Budius thanks for correcting, partially its a problem of addresses, addresses failed to explain question properly, even you also failed to understand.

Comment: I understand it's not copied, it's simply the only way of doing it. Feel free to up-vote my answer now ;)